# How do I call an array that I previously created in the main?

Tags: c++

I initialized an array called createAnArray with a size of 7. I made a method to fill createAnArray with integers. How do I use/call createAnArray values in another function? Do I have to create another for loop then call createAnArray[i]? I tried calling it in another function in a for loop but it keeps giving me a MEMORY LOCATION when I print it out. I'm trying to compare the index of the array I created with the one I stored in indexThatMatched.Any help would be great. Thanks guys.

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void printArray(int pinArray[], int arraysize);
void getArray(int anArray[], int arraysize);

int numToMatch[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int arrayOfNumbers[7] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int indexThatMatched[4]; // Want to add to this Array.
int createAnArray[7];
int main()
{
    getArray(createAnArray, 7);
}

void findMatch()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            indexThatMatched[i] = -1;
            if(numToMatch[i] == arrayOfNumbers[j]) // 
            {
                    cout << "Num " << numToMatch[i] << " ";
                    cout << "matches index " << arrayOfNumbers[j];
                    cout << endl;
                    indexThatMatched[i] = j;


            }
        }
    }
        printArray(indexThatMatched, 4);
}
void getArray(int anArray[], int arraysize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        anArray[i] = i;
    }
    printArray(anArray, 7);
}

void printArray(int anArray[], int arraysize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        cout << anArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're creating a global array, no need to pass that as a function argument, buddy. And, I tested this program. There's no "Memory Error".

Comment: This is wrong: `for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)` should be `< 7` but you passed in the length of the array as a parameter so better to use that: `for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `void getArray(int anArray[], int arraysize)`, the below for loop should run for only array size which is `7` but it is,

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
```

causing buffer overflow.

Secondly, when your array is declared as global, at the point on you can refer it which doesn't need any instance created per function where you use it. Please have a look at [Global Variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)